# Text cut off when saving as Photoshop PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, cs6

I have been having an issue lately when trying to save a A4 size document in Photoshop to PDF. When i save the document, some text on my PDF have the top and bottom of the text cut off making the middle of the text readable. I'll include some pictures to let you know what I mean:

[image]

I have tired a couple of things to fix the issue but none have yet to work out. I have tried shifting the text down, place in a new file, convert to paths or shapes...

I would love any help to try and fix this issue as I want to try and keep the font picked.

Comment: Have you flattened the image in Photoshop?

Comment: I am having the same problem. If I flatten the image, the text is pixellated. If I don't flatten, the top of the text is sheared.

Comment: I am also having this problem!!! anyone find a answer yet?